# Slide divs horizontal with materialize css

Tags: materialize

I need someone who knows materializecss to tell me is it possible to make this with materializecss? I googled but didnt find anything for materializecss.

So I am looking for somthing like in this example https://www.codeply.com/go/zAc3W2rzOd

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to slide divs in materializecss. You can actually find some examples at their website. [Click here](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html#one!) for the examples.

I simply copied one of their slider examples and pasted it into this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/flosommerfeld/gze9f688/) and the section below.

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top:100px;">
    <div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">
      <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
        <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2">button</a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
        <h2>First Panel</h2>
        <p class="white-text">This is your first panel</p>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
        <h2>Second Panel</h2>
        <p class="white-text">This is your second panel</p>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
        <h2>Third Panel</h2>
        <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
        <h2>Fourth Panel</h2>
        <p class="white-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script>
   $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({fullWidth: true});
  </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

In order to make these sliders work materializecss uses the jQuery plugin Carousel which also has some [options](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html#options).

Comment: I hope this is what you're looking for since the codeply which you posted does not work for me